# Using Reflector 2 between iPad Air 2 and PC Laptop

Tags: windows-7, ipad, mirroring, airplay

I'm having some issues with a user in my office who is looking to present her iPad screen to a laptop.

The iPad is an iPad Air 2 running iOS 9.1 and the laptop is a Lenovo T440p running Win7 Enterprise.

The laptop currently has installed the recently purchased Receiver application.

I have confirmed that both devices are connected to the same Wi-fi network. I have also attempted to connect them both to a second unsecured network.

In both cases, while the receiver app is running on the laptop, the Airplay cast button does not appear on the iPad.
 - Interestingly, the user can get Airplay to Reflector to work on her home PC.

Now, after downloading the Reflector Student app on the iPad (which was unnecessary for the user at home), I can scan the Receiver's QR code to pair and get the Airplay button to appear. Only problem being that even though the top status bar of the iPad changes to blue and it appears to be casting the screen, nothing appears on the laptop.

Edit: I have tried rebooting both the iPad and laptop. I am hoping that I won't need to reformat the iPad but if necessary, I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution, use Airserver. Works like a charm and does exactly what we want it to do. No issues whatsoever.